# Cocos2D-X compile Linux Error: Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, linux, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm new to cocos2D-X (v 3.6), I'm using Linux to compile and run my project. When I try the following command line:

```
cocos compile -p linux
```

It gives me errors:

```
Linking CXX executable bin/MyGame
CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp.o: In function `AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()':
/home/caisar/MyCompany/MyGame/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:53: undefined reference to `GraphicsScene::createScene()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/MyGame] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyGame.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Error running command, return code: 2
```

This is my `GraphicsScene.h`:

```
#ifndef __GRAPHICS_SCENE_H__
#define __GRAPHICS_SCENE_H__
#include "cocos2d.h"

class GraphicsScene : public cocos2d::Layer{
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();
    void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);
    CREATE_FUNC(GraphicsScene);
};

#endif
```

And this is my `GraphicsScene.cpp`:

```
#include "GraphicsScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* GraphicsScene::createScene(){
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = GraphicsScene::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}

bool GraphicsScene::init(){
    if(!Layer::init()){
        return false;
    }

    auto sprite = Sprite::create("autobot.png");
    sprite->setPosition(0,0);
    this->addChild(sprite, 0);

    return true;
}

void GraphicsScene::menuCloseCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
    Director::getInstance()->end();

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    exit(0);
#endif
}
```

Is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: I have got the same issue. Found a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem today and solved it by editing the `PROJECT_PATH/CMakeLists.txt` file. You must include the *.cpp and *.h filepaths in the `GAME_SRC` and `GAME_HEADERS` sections. For example, in your case it must be something like this:

```
set(GAME_SRC
  Classes/AppDelegate.cpp
  Classes/HelloWorld.cpp
  Classes/GraphicsScene.cpp
  ${PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_SRC}
)

set(GAME_HEADERS
  Classes/AppDelegate.h
  Classes/HelloWorld.h
  Classes/GraphicsScene.h
  ${PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_HEADERS}
)
```

Hope that it works!

Comment: does this update all the subprojects ie win32,android, android-studio etc

Comment: in my case I only tested the linux and android subprojects, and both worked.

Comment: so after updating this CMAKE file with my new source file, Do I need to run cocos compile -p linux or I run a CMAKE command

Comment: as far as I can remember, you only need to compile it (but I have not been working in the last year and a half with Cocos2d-x, so I'm not 100% sure. sorry about that)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the linker did not find the .cpp source file for GraphicsScene::createScene(). And you should add GraphicsScene.cpp to Android.mk file. Such as i did that for my project on windows.

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \

```
              ../../Classes/Graphic_Image.cpp \
```

Hope it help.
Thanks.